# Showing that the set of orthogonal matrices is Jordan-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, measure-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I will be restricting myself to $O(2)$ here to make things a bit easier. I will also be using Jordan measure.

I know that showing a set is measurable can be done by showing that its boundary has measure $0$. In the case of $O(2)$, I can show that every point in it is a boundary point. Meaning $O(2)=\partial\: O(2)$. So I am now trying to show that $O(2)$ is a nullset.

I had an idea to try to write $O(2)$ as the graph of an integrable function $f: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$. Then we have for $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_3\\x_2& f(x)\end{pmatrix} $$ and we want to build an integrable $f$ so that $\{(x,f(x)): \: x\in \mathbb{R}^3\} \cong O(2)$. The graph would be a nullset and so $O(2)$ as well.

However this doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to get the graph to cover the entirety of $O(2)$.

I would be grateful if I could get a tip to continue or maybe if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: $O(2)$ is a disjoint union of two circles in $M_2(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: @JohnDoe So you mean $\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi)\\ \sin(\phi) &\cos(\phi) \end{pmatrix}$ is a circle for $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$? Could you please explain how I can write the boundary of this circle as an integrable function?

Comment: That's $SO(2)$ one of the two circles.  The Frobenius and spectral norm of that matrix are both $1$ - so it's literally a circle of radius $1$ around the origin.  It's a compact 1-dimensional submanifold of $M_2(\Bbb{R})$ which is topologically $\Bbb{R}^4$ so it has empty interior and Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Correction: the Frobenius norm is actually $\sqrt{2}$ because the identity matrix has trace $2$.